# Poem where the narrator shrinks, smaller and smaller, into nothingness

Tags: story-identification, poetry

The poem is about a kid who for some reason is shrinking and is afraid he(?) will disappear. I think it was written in first person but I really don't remember much more about the story than that. There weren't many lines in it, maybe 20 total broken into 5 stanzas, though I considered this to be a long poem at the time. Being a poem, it must have rhymed.

The memorable and unique part of it is that a little into the poem, the lines started getting smaller, just like the kid.

<sub>And smaller.</sub>

<sub><sub>And even smaller. You could barely read the end.</sub></sub>

I read it in English in 2004 as a child and I thought it was from one of Shel Silverstein's poetry anthologies. But now, I looked at the titles in all three relevant anthologies of his (Where the Sidewalk Ends, Falling Up, A Light in the Attic) and looked up the ones that looked like they could match to read them, but couldn't find the one I'm looking for.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

My inability to stop looking led me to the answer: *[I am Shrinking](https://victorki.blogspot.com/2004/07/i-am-shrinking.html?m=1)* from "It's Raining Pigs and Noodles" by Jack Prelutsky.

I couldn't find a picture of the formatting, but I recognized it from just the words. However, one [book review](https://lfosterbookreview.blogspot.com/2007/10/its-raining-pigs-and-noodles-genre.html?m=1) mentions it:

> Shape poems such as *I Am Shrinking*, in which the text gets progressively smaller and smaller until it nearly disappears on the page will engage children and encourage them to attempt to read to find out the end... that is if they can read print that tiny!